# getting error in project......Here is my code

Tags: spring-webflow

It is not identifying the `initFlow()` method in `FlowController`

Here is my `FlowController`

```
 FlowController.java :-
-----------------------------------

    package com.niit.shoppingcart;

import java.util.List;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.niit.shoppingcart.dao.BillingAddressDAO;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.dao.CardDetailDAO;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.dao.CartDAO;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.dao.OrderDetailDAO;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.dao.OrderedItemsDAO;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.dao.ProductDAO;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.dao.ShippingAddressDAO;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.dao.UserDetailsDAO;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.BillingAddress;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.CardDetail;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.Cart;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.CheckoutDetails;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.OrderDetail;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.OrderedItems;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.Product;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.ShippingAddress;
import com.niit.shoppingcart.model.UserDetails;



@Component(value="flowController")
public class FlowController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductDAO productDAO;

    @Autowired
    private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;

    @Autowired
    private BillingAddress billingAddress;

    @Autowired
    private OrderDetail orderDetail;

    @Autowired
    private OrderedItems orderedItems;

    @Autowired
    private CardDetail cardDetail;

    @Autowired
    private ShippingAddressDAO shippingAddressDAO;

    @Autowired
    private BillingAddressDAO billingAddressDAO;

    @Autowired
    private OrderedItemsDAO orderedItemsDAO;

    @Autowired
    private OrderDetailDAO orderDetailDAO;

    @Autowired
    private CardDetailDAO cardDetailDAO;
    @Autowired
    UserDetails userDetails;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsDAO  userDetailsDAO ;

    @Autowired
    CartDAO cartDAO;

    @Autowired
    List<Cart> cart;


    @Autowired
    HttpSession httpSession;
    @Autowired
    Product product;


    public ShippingAddress initFlow() {

        return new ShippingAddress();
    }

    public String saveDetails(ShippingAddress shippingAddress){

         /*Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
          String name = auth.getName();
            UserDetails userDetails=userDetailsDAO.getCustomerByUserName(name);
            String loggedInUser = userDetails.getId();
          shippingAddress.setUserId(loggedInUser);*/
        shippingAddressDAO.saveOrUpdate(shippingAddress);

        return "success";
    }
    public String saveDetails(BillingAddress billingAddress){

         /*Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
          String name = auth.getName();
            UserDetails userDetails=userDetailsDAO.getCustomerByUserName(name);
            String loggedInUser = userDetails.getId();
          billingAddress.setUserId(loggedInUser);*/
        billingAddressDAO.saveOrUpdate(billingAddress);
        return "success";
    }
    public String saveDetails(CardDetail cardDetail){
        /*Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
          String name = auth.getName();
            UserDetails userDetails=userDetailsDAO.getCustomerByUserName(name);
            String loggedInUser = userDetails.getId();
          cardDetail.setUserId(loggedInUser);*/
        cardDetailDAO.saveOrUpdate(cardDetail);
        return "success";   
    }


    /*public String remove(){
         Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
          String name = auth.getName();
            UserDetails userDetails=userDetailsDAO.getCustomerByUserName(name);
            String loggedInUser = userDetails.getId();
            List<Cart> cartList = cartDAO.getByUser(loggedInUser);
            if (cartList != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cartList.size(); i++) {
                cartList.get(i).setQuantity(0);
                cartDAO.update(cartList.get(i));
                }

            }
            return "success";

}*/
}



    ===============================================================================
```

Here is my checkout-flow.xml

checkout-flow.xml :-
    ----------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow  http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.4.xsd">

    <var name="shippingAddress" class="com.niit.shoppingcart.model.ShippingAddress" />
    <var name="billingAddress" class="com.niit.shoppingcart.model.BillingAddress" />
    <var name="orderedItems" class="com.niit.shoppingcart.model.OrderedItems" />
    <var name="orderDetail" class="com.niit.shoppingcart.model.OrderDetail" />
        <var name="CardDetail" class="com.niit.shoppingcart.model.CardDetail" />
    <var name="cart" class="com.niit.shoppingcart.model.Cart" />
        <var name="UserDetails" class="com.niit.shoppingcart.model.UserDetails" />
    <var name="checkoutDetails" class="com.niit.shoppingcart.model.CheckoutDetails"></var>

    <on-start>
        <evaluate expression="flowController.initFlow()" result="flowScope.shippingAddress" />
    </on-start>

    <view-state id="start" view="shippingAddress" model="flowScope.shippingAddress">
        <transition on="submitShippingAddress" to="saveShipping" />
        <transition on="back" to="toHome" />
    </view-state>
        <action-state id="saveShipping">
        <evaluate expression="flowController.saveDetails(shippingAddress)"></evaluate>
        <transition on="success" to="viewBillingDetails" />
    </action-state>

 <!-- <action-state id="shippingDetails">
        <evaluate
            expression="flowController.addShippingAddress(flowScope.checkoutDetails,flowScope.shippingAddress)"></evaluate>
        <transition on="success" to="viewBillingDetails" />
            <transition on="failure" to="start" />
    </action-state>  -->

    <view-state id="viewBillingDetails" view="billingAddress" model="flowScope.billingAddress">
        <transition on="submitBillingAddress" to="saveBilling" />
        <transition on="cancel" to="start" />
    </view-state>

        <action-state id="saveBilling">
        <evaluate expression="flowController.saveDetails(billingAddress)"></evaluate>
        <transition on="success" to="viewCardDetail" />
    </action-state>

    <!-- <action-state id="billingDetails">
        <evaluate
            expression="flowController.addBillingAddress(flowScope.checkoutDetails,billingAddress)"></evaluate>
        <transition on="success" to="viewCardDetail" />``
    </action-state> -->

    <view-state id="viewCardDetail" view="cardDetail"
        model="cardDetail">
        <transition on="confirmCheckout" to="save" />
            <transition on="cancel" to="viewBillingDetails" />
    </view-state>

    <!-- <action-state id="cardDetail">
        <evaluate
            expression="flowController.addCardDetails(flowScope.checkoutDetails,cardDetail)"></evaluate>
        <transition on="success" to="orderConfirm" />
    </action-state> -->

    <action-state id="save">
        <evaluate expression="flowController.saveDetails(cardDetail)"></evaluate>
        <transition on="success" to="orderConfirm" />

    </action-state>


    <view-state id="orderConfirm" view="orderConfirmed">
        <!-- <transition on="finalHome" to="remove" /> -->
        <transition on="finalHome" to="toHome" />
    </view-state>

<!-- <action-state id="remove">
        <evaluate expression="FlowController.remove()"></evaluate>
        <transition on="success" to="toHome" />
    </action-state>  -->


    <!-- <end-state id="orderConfirmed" view="orderConfirmed"/> 
    <end-state id="toCartView" view="externalRedirect:contextRelative:/user/cart/" /> -->
    <end-state id="toHome" view="Home" />

<global-transitions>
        <transition on="back" to="Home" />
    </global-transitions> 

</flow>
```

Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml, i have given the entries of checkoutDetails....

```
 dispatcher-servlet.xml:-

------------------------------------------------------

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.4.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.niit.shoppingcart" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="200000" />
    </bean>
     <bean 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>


    <!-- Using FlowController instead of FlowHandlers; see SWF Reference Guide, section 9.5. -->

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.niit.shoppingcart.*" />

    <bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
    </bean>

    <flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry"/>

    <!-- This creates an XmlFlowRegistryFactory bean -->
    <flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF">
    <flow:flow-location id="memberShip" path="/memberShipFlow.xml"/> 
        <flow:flow-location id="checkoutDetails" path="/checkout-flow.xml"/>
    </flow:flow-registry>

    <flow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator"/>

        <bean id="viewFactoryCreator"
        class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="viewResolver" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix">
           <value>/view/</value>
         </property>
         <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
         </property>
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>




</beans>


===============================================================================
```

Here is my error report:-

```
Error Report :-
--------------------------------------------------


SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/ShoppingCartFrontEnd] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@2e7a1b64 targetAction = [EvaluateAction@3bb088b8 expression = flowController.initFlow(), resultExpression = flowScope.shippingAddress], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'null' of flow 'checkoutDetails' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 15): Method call: Method initFlow() cannot be found on org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController type
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:211)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:125)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:347)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:154)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:526)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:368)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:223)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<bean id="flowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</bean>
```

Your `FlowController.java` file has:

```
package com.niit.shoppingcart;
```

At the head, so that would mean that the full name of your bean should be:

```
<bean id="flowController" class="com.niit.shoppingcart.FlowController">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</bean>
```

Does that help you?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 beans named flowController. One of them is a spring bean for your configuration, the other is the bean you use in this order flow.

I suggest you change:

```
@Component(value="flowController")
```

to something like:

```
@Component(value="checkoutFlowController")
```

and then all references to it in your checkout-flow as well:

```
<evaluate expression="checkoutFlowController.initFlow()" result="flowScope.shippingAddress" />
```

etc.